# not able to read value using ngmodel

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding, ngmodel

Not able to read value and bind it in a variable using ng model. shows as undefined in console

xx.ts

```
  let searchText='';
   console.log(searchText)
```

xx.html

```
 <input class="ml-3" [(ngModel)]="searchText"  
    class="gwt-TextBox" name="search" #search="ngModel"/>
```

Result:

```
console
undefined
```

Comment: Your variable "searchTest" should be a variable of the component. Please, take a [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes) to know the basic of Angular

Answer (score 0):

In angular, variable can be declared without using keywords like let or var
& while using that variable we need to add 'this' keyword

Modify your .ts file code as below :

```
searchText='';
console.log(this.searchText);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the variable as any in the .ts file
Like this,

```
searchText: any;
```